# passportJS: using a user id field named other than id

Tags: mysql, node.js, passport-local

I found this great node mysql boilerplate:

https://github.com/ocastillo/nodejs-mysql-boilerplate

it works terrific! However, now I need to hook it in to my existing user table, and my key field is named userID, not simply id, and changing the key fieldname in mysql breaks the example. So my question is, where in the project do I need to specify a different id field name? I see user.id in /util/auth.js  passport.serializeUser and id in passport.deserializeUser functions, but it seems it must be specified elsewhere too. I'm hoping this is a simple question for users of passportjs!

Comment: I actually have the same issue right now. Have you already found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should only need to change the code in the `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions.  Those two functions you control, and state within them what you'd like to serialize into the session cookie (when the user logs in), and deserialize from the session cookie (when the user revisits the site after logging in).  Think of them as ways to remember who this person is, once they return.  The `passport.use` function is only used to define the authentication strategy, and within that, the manner in which you'll "log the user in".

So this should work (assuming I've followed what you've said above):

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.userID);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(user_id, done) {
    new data.ApiUser({userID: user_id}).fetch().then(function(user) {
        return done(null, user);
    }, function(error) {
        return done(error);
    });
});
```

You might benefit from more examples, here's a gist I put together on passport configuration within Node (however this one uses Mongo): https://gist.github.com/dylants/8030433

Comment: By the way, I've found a debugger very useful in inspecting what is available to me within the code (for instance, seeing what's available from the `user` variable).  I'd recommend installing [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector), then firing it up and stepping through that code to better understand it.

Comment: (you beat me to it!) thank you! your edit is exactly what I tried...  

when I use node-inspector to step in to passport.authenticate, the user object lacks an id property (though I see userID under user.attributes).  

then when I proceed through passport.serializeUser, I get the error:
Error: Failed to serialize user into session.

however, if I revert my userID change to both those 2 functions and to the example database column name, and step in to passport.authenticate, the user.id exists. So it seems there is another place where user.id is being set.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a bit confused now.  You're saying that it works with the `user.id` code, but does not with `user.userID`?  I was under the impression that the logic did _not_ work with `user.id`.  Know that you can put whatever you want in the `serializeUser`'s `done` call, and it will be sent in the `deserializeUser`'s first input argument.  I've just tested this by using the user's name rather than ID.  How the code handles looking up the user in `deserializeUser` is perhaps what's missing?

Comment: it works with user.id IF I set the key field (in the example database) to be named id. if I rename the id field to userID in that database, then update the 2 references mentioned above, it stops working.

Comment: Then yes, I would say this is more of a configuration issue with bookshelf, or the database configuration logic, rather than a Passport issue.  Sorry I'm not able to debug that area of your code.  You might try isolating the issue, or simplifying the code base to help you further.

Comment: thanks for your help. were you so inclined (though I don't expect it!) the problem can be reproduced by downloading that gist then renaming as outlined above. I'll keep researching!